# Why does k-NN perform better than SVR and linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-mining, optimization

I have a data set used in a regression with 30 attributes and 30K instances. I am trying out a bunch of algorithms (SMO regression, Linear Regression and K-NN) but it was quite surprising to see that K-NN performs much better than SMO and Linear Regression.

Since K-NN is a very naive algorithm compared with at least SMO, I was expecting to get better results for SMO algorithm.

All results are with 10-fold cross validation:

```
Algorithm | Correlation coef. | Root mean square error
SMO       | 0.6861            | 2225232   
K-NN      | 0.9133            | 1192372
Linear    | 0.7621            | 1853795
```

What can be the reason for this? Can there be a problem in my dataset or K-NN just happened to be the best algorithm that can explain my data?

On a side note: when I depict the actual SMO regression model, I can see that some attributes are rated negatively. Does it shows that some of my attributes are not independent from each other? So that SMO build a bad model because of this?

Here is my model for SMO:

```
weights (not support vectors):
 +       0.3724 * (normalized) a1
 +       0.0062 * (normalized) a2
 -       1.6342 * (normalized) a3
 +       0.0909 * (normalized) a4
 -       0.2963 * (normalized) a5
 +       0.8106 * (normalized) a6
 -       0.1123 * (normalized) a7
 -       0.4488 * (normalized) a8
 +       0.0406 * (normalized) a9
 -       1.2222 * (normalized) a10
 +       1.7119 * (normalized) a11
 -       0.1321 * (normalized) a12
 +       0.0292 * (normalized) a13
 +       0.54   * (normalized) a14
 -       0.3266 * (normalized) a15
 -       0.3521 * (normalized) a16
 -       0.1737 * (normalized) a17
 +       0.0829 * (normalized) a18
 -       0.1706 * (normalized) a19
 -       0.0909 * (normalized) a20
 -       0.4802 * (normalized) a21
 +       0.0077 * (normalized) a22
 +       0.029  * (normalized) a23
 -       0.03   * (normalized) a24
 -       0.1366 * (normalized) a25
 +       0.1647 * (normalized) a26
 -       0.0312 * (normalized) a27
 +       0.1972 * (normalized) a28
 -       0.104  * (normalized) a29
 +       0      * (normalized) a30
 -       0.0575 * (normalized) a31
 +       0.0215
```

A second sidenote: Also the distribution of my attributes are pretty skewed. Can this also be the reason why K-NN beats others? (because of the majority vote problem in K-NN algorithm?)

Comment: How many times did you re-run the test.  Replication can indicate variation (or consistency) in results.

Comment: The fact that kNN can beat SVM is not really surprising, nevertheless I somewhat feel your problem will look way better after taking a log of decision (at least).

Comment: @mbq Sorry, I am somewhat confused. Do you mean that I should take the log of the prediction (SVM's output) before calculating the correlation coefficient?

Comment: Rather log the decision before both making a model and calculating correlation coefficient. If your values have a huge and skewed spread neither SVR optimization target nor Pearson correlation make any sense.

Comment: What types of SVR have you tried? Did you also try to use non-linear kernels? One possibility is that your outcome is not a linear function of your data. Also, the fact that your data contain 30 predictors and 30k instances may be a reason why KNN works that well, as the dimensionality is not that high (KNN struggles with high-dimensional data) and 30k instances seem to be sufficient (KNN usually needs many samples).